# UILongPressGestureRecognizer sometimes take to fail recognizer of other gestures

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

My UILongPressGestureRecognizer sometimes take to fail  recognizer of other gestures.
I cannot understand the exact pattern that break the recognizer of the 2 single tap gesture. I think it will happen if the user click a lot of time on my UIImageView.
I think that is related to the logic of my code... but I can't understand where is the fail.
Thanks

```
 // adding tap gesture recognizers to the image view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap)] autorelease];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap)] autorelease];
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longTap = [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlelongTap)] autorelease];

    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];


    longTap.minimumPressDuration=0.70;
    longTap.numberOfTouchesRequired=1;



    [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];

    [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:longTap];
    [doubleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:longTap];

    [longTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:singleTap];


    // adding drag and drop gesture recognizers to the image view
    UIGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pan:)] autorelease];

    //Adding gestures to the imageView
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:longTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

Comment: Remove `[longTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:singleTap];`.  If the longtap takes the touch event then the singletap can not because it requires the long tap to fail.

Comment: Doesn't work! Any other suggestions?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to happen, nor what is currently happening.  My suggestion would be to check what is firing when and what interferes with what running.  It sounds like one of your recognizer functions is stopping another recognizer function from running properly.  Without more information I have no idea.

Comment: are you trying to say that your `handlelongTap` method is called multiple times ?